# synchronous to asynchronus using jms queue

Tags: jsf, jms

I Need to create a Server side jms queue to handle the requests and responses. I am using Richfaces in Jsf 2.0 and Apache Tomcat server,In the Managed bean I am getting synchronously  comma separated values values from yahoo fiance but I wanted to get them asynchronously and spontaneously display the values 
 I don't want to change to different frame work. 
I don't know how to create and implement queue  please help me with some examples.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling your code recursively until it reach stack limit.

Then stackoverflow exception is thrown.

This has nothing to do with ajax, jsf-2.0 or richfaces at all, please remove tags.

I expect getResult method is called recursively.

Comment: can you please be specific where it went wrong because i am not using getResult method any where

Comment: Run it in debugger and check call stack.You will see it!

Answer (score 0):

"value="#{StockQuoterBean.Symbols}": Property 'Symbols' not found on ty"
Because you have a get and setter for Symbols -> getSymbols and setSymbols. Then you have to use in your jsf page symbols in stead of Symbols (so lowercase)

```
#{StockQuoterBean.symbols}
```

Comment: what errors, the same? Then your source is not updated on the server.

Comment: I have updated the source code  in the server and when i try to run the project I got the above errors (I have updated the errors above)

Comment: I have updated my code with getter and settor methods the code is working but when i have tried to use <h:outputText value="#{StockQuoterBean.Results}"/> i am getting error /index.xhtml @10,59 value="#{StockQuoterBean.Results}": Property 'Results' not found on type StockQuoter.StockQuoterBean

Comment: How can i access the array of strings in component from bean

Comment: You should use #{StockQuoterBean.results}. The same problem as above. GetResults -> in jsf page -> .results  not .Results

Comment: you should use a component that can handle arrays. Use a repeat to display en array. Or display it as this <h:inputText value="#{StockQuoterBean.results[0]}"/> and <h:inputText value="#{StockQuoterBean.results[1]}"/>  Witch is bad code. Just an example of an array. Use <ui:repeat var="result" value="#{StockQuoterBean.results}">

Comment: no not at i just learned how to use managed beans i need to create a queue which handles the requests and responses and i should implement using richfaces and need to complete my lab I have mentioned above in the question

Comment: Nobody's gonna make your lab for you on stackoverflow. But we will help in specific problems. So state your problem specifically and you might get a useful answer. Ask to solve a lab and you will be ignored.

Comment: no I am not asking to someone to do my lab I am asking help to solve my problems so i have posted my code so that someone can tell me what mistakes i have done in code

Comment: Ok. But what is your problem now? Because you changed things so some errors schould be solved. But what problem do you still have?

Comment: I Need to handle requests and responses using server side queue and the process should be asynchronous

Comment: That doesn't sound like a specific problem too me. Do you have a stacktrace or other error. Be more specific please. And it has nothing to do with the above error. So open en new question.